# Java / Android Programming - Loop FAIL

Tags: java, android

I am using a while loop with a timer.
The thing is that the timer is not used in every loop.
It is used only the first time. After the first time the statements included inside the loop are executed without the delay that i have set.
How is this even possible since the timer is included inside the while loop.
Any solutions ?

```
        int count = 1;
        while (count <= 10) {
            final Handler handler = new Handler();
            Timer t = new Timer();
            t.schedule(new TimerTask() {
                public void run() {
                    handler.post(new Runnable() {
                        public void run() {

                        // Stuff the while loop executes
                    }
                    });
                }
            }, 20000);
            count++;
        }
```

Comment: Er. You are starting ten separate timers to do the task. ... Is this what you wanted?

Answer (score 1):

The `TimerTask` kicks off a new Thread and then the loop proceeds as normal.

The execution of the thread does not cause a delay to the execution of the code in your loop.

Comment: Let me give you an eg of what i'm trying to do...

I simply want to toast something once an hour. In other words "// Stuff the while loop executes" i want what's in there to be executed once an hour.

Comment: I'd submit another question being very specific about what you're trying to achieve and showing code that demonstrates what you've already tried.

Answer (score 0):

It's because you're queueing up 10 toasts all to execute in one hour. Each iteration of your loop takes only a fraction of a millisecond or maybe a tad bit more than that. To enqueue them properly, you could do 3600000 * count instead of 3600000 each time.

This is a terrible way to do it though. You should use AlarmManager for stuff like this.

Answer (score 0):

You're scheduling 10 `TimerTask`s to execute after an hour, at the same time. So all 10 tasks are being executed after 1 hour, which makes it seem like 1 execute since all the `Toast` messages display at the same time. To schedule tasks at a fixed delay, with the first task starting in 1 hour, use this method:

```
Timer t = new Timer();
t.schedule(task, 3600000, 3600000);
```

This will execute until you call `t.cancel()`.